# How to set Brush of QGraphicsRectItem in QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, user-interface, graphics

I am trying to set Brush of 5 QGraphicsRectItem by setBrush using QBrush. but it doesn't work. The behavior is confusing as it works in some cases.

[image: example image]

The code includes a *.ui which I have created in Qt-Creator. I have added a QGraphiocsView on it.

```js
QGraphicsScene *scene_;

scene_ = new QGraphicsScene(ui->graphicsView);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene_);

scene_->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::red);


for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    QBrush tmpBrush;
    tmpBrush.setColor( QColor(200-i*15, i*15, 50) );
    QPen tmpPen;
    tmpPen.setColor(Qt::blue);        tmpPen.setWidth(2);

    QGraphicsRectItem*tmpRect = scene_->addRect( 2, 25*i, 100, 20, tmpPen, tmpBrush );
    tmpRect->setPen(tmpPen);          tmpRect->setBrush(tmpBrush);
}
```

I'm coding with QT 5.7 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your brush has no style :-)  Or, perhaps more helpfully, you create a new `QBrush` with...

```
QBrush tmpBrush;
```

That invokes the default constructor whose [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#QBrush) states

> Constructs a default black brush with the style Qt::NoBrush (i.e. this
>   brush will not fill shapes).

So, just change it to...

```
QBrush tmpBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
```

and you should get the desired result.

Comment: thanks! It was helpful and the code is running correctly now